# Is java main method a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

I was wondering if Java main method was a thread or not. I noticed that if the main method returns, all threads are killed. Can you explain me why this happens?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "If the main method returns, all threads are killed" ... I don't observe this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the main method runs on the Main thread ! The `main threads invokes your main()`

All the other threads of a java application are spawned from this thread !

Answer (score 1):

When you start your application the OS create a Thread for you which is the main thread (or UI thread in other contexts).

This thread just run your `main` method and stop.
Anyway there are two types of threads.

- User thread
- Daemon threads

The `main thread` is a `User thread`.
The JVM will be stopped when all user threads are finished.

Well, it's just a "fast response" i'm pretty use you can found better answer by experts here.

Comment: No, your answer is pretty good, especially where you point out that the program does _not_ end just because the main thread ends, but only when _all_ of the non-daemon threads have ended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, main method runs on the main thread. But it still is like any other user thread.

There are Daemon threads too which stop when all other user threads have stopped running.

Main thread is also responsible for spawning other threads that the programmer creates in his program, which can in turn spawn other threads and so on.

And its not that when main method returns all thread get killed. One reason could be because main is a void method, and it can't return anything. :D

But keeping the pun aside, if you spawn one or more user threads which run for long time, and you don't use `join()` method in your `main` method then even if the main method ends, the other threads still run, if their `run()` method hasn't stopped executing.